# MVC native identity - from Code-First to Database-First navigation property error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, identity

In transforming my application from Code-First to Database-First, I use the Code-First generated identity database tables, but an error appears:

> A specified Include path is not valid. The EntityType
>   'MyAppModel.AspNetUser' does not declare a navigation property with
>   the name 'Roles'.

Thanks in advance!